# How to set up an Express 4.0 application

Tags: node.js, express

I downloaded express today from npm, and to my surprise, it gave me express 4.0.0 instead of express 3.x.x.

I'm trying to configure a basic server with connect logger and body parser, but I'm not having much luck.

Could someone provide me with a boilerplate app.js file using express 4.0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

You can get a skeleton app using:

```
$ npm install -g express-generator
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can swap out the connect logger and body parser for their connect standalone siblings (and it might be useful for learning what each middleware does, rather than relying on the generator to throw together a bunch of dependencies you may not need):

(based on [Express 3.x to 4.x Migration guide](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware))

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();
...
server.use(require('body-parser')); //previously bodyparser (or rather urlencoded/json)
server.use(require('morgan')());  //previously connect-logger
...
server.listen('3000', function() {
    console.log('server started');
});
```